# Convert String to Dict or List in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

convert this string to list or dictionary in python?

```
['[', '{', 'u', "'", 'f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', '_', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', "'", ':', ' ', 'u', "'", 'j', 'o', 'h', 'n', "'", ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'l', 'a', 's', 't', '_', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', "'", ':', ' ', 'u', "'", 's', 'm', 'i', 't', 'h', "'", ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'a', 'g', 'e', "'", ':', ' ', '2', '0', ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'm', 'o', 'b', 'n', 'u', 'm', "'", ':', ' ', 'u', "'", '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '9', '0', '8', "'", ',', ' ', 'u', "'", '_', 'i', 'd', "'", ':', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'e', 'm', 'a', 'i', 'l', "'", ':', ' ', 'u', "'", 's', 'm', 'i', 't', 'h', '@', 'g', 'm', 'a', 'i', 'l', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm', "'", '}', ']']
```

Comment: Are you saying that the characters `['[', '{', 'u', "'",...` are stored in a Python string?

Comment: And what's the desired output?

Comment: it should be [{"first_name":"john","last_name":"smith","age":20....}]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> a = ['[', '{', 'u', "'", 'f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', '_', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', "'", ':', ' ', 'u', "'", 'j', 'o', 'h', 'n', "'", ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'l', 'a', 's', 't', '_', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', "'", ':', ' ', 'u', "'", 's', 'm', 'i', 't', 'h', "'", ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'a', 'g', 'e', "'", ':', ' ', '2', '0', ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'm', 'o', 'b', 'n', 'u', 'm', "'", ':', ' ', 'u', "'", '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '9', '0', '8', "'", ',', ' ', 'u', "'", '_', 'i', 'd', "'", ':', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'e', 'm', 'a', 'i', 'l', "'", ':', ' ', 'u', "'", 's', 'm', 'i', 't', 'h', '@', 'g', 'm', 'a', 'i', 'l', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm', "'", '}', ']']

>>> ''.join(a)
     "[{u'first_name': u'john', u'last_name': u'smith', u'age': 20, u'mobnum': u'12341908', u'_id': 1, u'email': u'smith@gmail.com'}]"

>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(''.join(a))
 [{u'_id': 1,
  u'age': 20,
  u'email': u'smith@gmail.com',
  u'first_name': u'john',
  u'last_name': u'smith',
  u'mobnum': u'12341908'}]
```

How did you manage to get that?

Comment: @Janardhan: what you have is a list of characters, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

It is itself a list and you are saying to convert it to list! *Try print type(a)* by assigning given code as *a* !! Then you will get

```
<type 'list'>
```

as output!