# Trouble reading a file into an array python because of added ' '

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x, file

I have written a simple connect 4 game in python, and I am having trouble loading the board; whenever it reads from the file using this code, it then reads board to be ['[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', '[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', '[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', '[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', '[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]'], which causes problems later on within the game because of the ' '. How do I get rid of these?

The game document looks like this;

Player 1

Player 2

1

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

And this below is the code i am using to load the game.

```
f = open("game.txt", mode="rt", encoding="utf8") 
    game = {} 
    lines = f.readlines() 
    board = []
    for i in range(3, 8):
        lines[i] = lines[i].strip('\n')
        board.append(lines[i])
    game.update({'player 1 :': lines[0]})
    game.update({'player 2 :': lines[1]})
    game.update({'who : ': lines[2]})
    game.update({'board : ': board})
    return game
```

Comment: try evaluating the lines using `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String to Dict or List in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404352/convert-string-to-dict-or-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need for literal evaluation. simply use eval, that should do the trick

```
board.append(eval(lines[i]))
```

Comment: Anytime. Have a great weekend